# Dash - search and display results in datatable

Tags: python, dataframe, datatable, plotly-dash

I have a dataframe of patient records as rows and various features as columns.

I'd like to be able to search through this dataframe based on one feature and display the rows that correspond to that search in a Dash DataTable.

What's the best way to do this? I understand DataTables have their own native filtering function, but is it possible to filter based on a user-entered value from an input field or dropdown value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, completely doable. You need a callback for that. It will take as input the value of the dropdown, or input field, and its output will be the `data` prop for the table component. Inside the callback, you can filter your dataframe based on the input value.

Depending on where you load the data for the table from, you may want to put the original, unfiltered data in something like a `dcc.Store` and pass that to your callback as a state value, to avoid having to make network or database calls repeatedly.

Comment: How can I filter the dataframe based on say a freeform text input, like how the dcc.Dropdown searches? I understand .loc and .query are possible filtering/searching methods for dataframes, but not sure how to approach freeform searching

Comment: It might be good to limit to a specific column. You could pair a dropdown menu, which lists the columns, and a text input field, where the user can enter the value they want to filter on for that column. With pattern-matching callbacks, you could even allow the user to add multiple filters with these dropdown & input pairs.